# How to theme OutlinedButton?

Tags: flutter, themes

I've tried using ButtonStyle, but it asks for MaterialStateProperty for some reason:

```
outlinedButtonTheme: OutlinedButtonThemeData(
   style: ButtonStyle(backgroundColor: ... )
),
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set outlined button themes as below since flutter version 1.20. Refer below code segment

```
return MaterialApp(
      home: Home(),
      theme: ThemeData.from(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(),
      ).copyWith(
        outlinedButtonTheme: OutlinedButtonThemeData(
          style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
            primary: Colors.purple,
            backgroundColor: Colors.green,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Why the -1?, this answer is working and is solving what the question asks.